# CXF DOSGI ZOOKEEPER

Tags: service, osgi, apache-zookeeper, dosgi

Good morning,

I'm looking for help please.I'm only a beginner.

I am using cxf-dosgi from (DOSGi Apache Karaf Feature distribution)

I want to make transparent use of services between two remote machines. So I have a karaf container on each of these two machines.

---

I tested this  [example](http://liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2013/02/13/Apache+Karaf+Tutorial+Part+8+-+Distributed+OSGi) : to start with two containers karaf hosted on the same machine then I changed the configuration to test with two containers hosted on two different remote machines. And it works great !

So I want to do the same thing to export to export my web services. I am using Spring DM. So I do this on the server side :

```
<osgi:service id="osgi-service" ref="myservice" interface="org.apache.camel.Endpoint"> <osgi:service-properties> <entry key="name" value="service"/> <entry key="service.exported.interfaces" value="*"/> </osgi:service-properties> </osgi:service>
```

I did the installations like  in the tutorial with cxf dosgi version 1.6 But I get this error:

```
16:25:53,256 | ERROR | pool-21-thread-3 | w.service.RemoteServiceAdminCore  193 | 184 - cxf-dosgi-ri-dsw-cxf - 1.6.0 | failed to create server for interface org.apache.camel.Endpoint
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.reflect.Array.newArray(Native Method)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:70)[:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.TypeUtil.getTypeRelatedClass(TypeUtil.java:259)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.AbstractTypeCreator.createTypeForClass(AbstractTypeCreator.java:108)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.AbstractTypeCreator.createType(AbstractTypeCreator.java:402)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.basic.BeanTypeInfo.getType(BeanTypeInfo.java:192)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.basic.BeanType.getDependencies(BeanType.java:547)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding.addDependencies(AegisDatabinding.java:394)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding.addDependencies(AegisDatabinding.java:399)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding.addDependencies(AegisDatabinding.java:399)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding.initializeMessage(AegisDatabinding.java:371)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding.initializeOperation(AegisDatabinding.java:283)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding.initialize(AegisDatabinding.java:242)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:490)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:550)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159)
    at org.apache.cxf.dosgi.dsw.handlers.AbstractPojoConfigurationTypeHandler.createServerFromFactory(AbstractPojoConfigurationTypeHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.cxf.dosgi.dsw.handlers.PojoConfigurationTypeHandler.createServer(PojoConfigurationTypeHandler.java:119)
    at org.apache.cxf.dosgi.dsw.service.RemoteServiceAdminCore.exportInterfaces(RemoteServiceAdminCore.java:184)
    at org.apache.cxf.dosgi.dsw.service.RemoteServiceAdminCore.exportService(RemoteServiceAdminCore.java:140)
    at org.apache.cxf.dosgi.dsw.service.RemoteServiceAdminInstance$1.run(RemoteServiceAdminInstance.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.dosgi.dsw.service.RemoteServiceAdminInstance$1.run(RemoteServiceAdminInstance.java:57)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.cxf.dosgi.dsw.service.RemoteServiceAdminInstance.exportService(RemoteServiceAdminInstance.java:57)[184:cxf-dosgi-ri-dsw-cxf:1.6.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.dosgi.dsw.service.RemoteServiceAdminInstance.exportService(RemoteServiceAdminInstance.java:41)[184:cxf-dosgi-ri-dsw-cxf:1.6.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.exporter.TopologyManagerExport.exportServiceUsingRemoteServiceAdmin(TopologyManagerExport.java:185)[183:cxf-dosgi-ri-topology-manager:1.6.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.exporter.TopologyManagerExport.doExportService(TopologyManagerExport.java:168)[183:cxf-dosgi-ri-topology-manager:1.6.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.exporter.TopologyManagerExport$3.run(TopologyManagerExport.java:143)[183:cxf-dosgi-ri-topology-manager:1.6.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_79]
```

Have you an idea of what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ouch .. what are you doing with 1.4-SNAPSHOT. First it is not a release and second it is quite old.

Another thing that looks suspicious is the service.exported.interfaces=myInterface. It should be a fully qualified java interface name. For the start try service.exported.interfaces=* for it.

You should start with my [CXF DOSGi tutorial](http://liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2013/02/13/Apache+Karaf+Tutorial+Part+8+-+Distributed+OSGi). The code there should work out of the box. You can then add your changes in the config. So it is easier than to start completely new.

Comment: Thank you for your response Christian, I'll try your cxf dosgi tutorial . Does this example work  between two remote machines? About this property: service.exported.interfaces = MyInterface. It is just an example. In fact, i'm using org.apache.camel.Endpoint interface.

Comment: I tested the example:  to start with two containers karaf hosted on the same machine then I changed the configuration to test with two containers hosted on two different remote machines. And it works great!

Comment: I want to just do the same thing to export my web services. I am using Spring DM.
So I do this on the server side :

Comment: <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="myservice" 
  address="http://localhost:8181/application/analyser" serviceClass="org.my.web.services.Analyser">
  <cxf:properties>
   <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD" />
   <entry key="allowStreaming" value="true" />
  </cxf:properties>
 </cxf:cxfEndpoint>

Comment: <osgi:service id="osgi-service" ref="myservice" interface="org.apache.camel.Endpoint">
            <osgi:service-properties>
      <entry key="name" value="service"/>
  <entry key="service.exported.interfaces" value="*"/>
      </osgi:service-properties>
</osgi:service>

Comment: I have performed the installations as in the tutorial with version 1.6 But I get this error:

Comment: 16:25:53,256 | ERROR | pool-21-thread-3 | w.service.RemoteServiceAdminCore  193 | 184 - cxf-dosgi-ri-dsw-cxf - 1.6.0 | failed to create server for interface org.apache.camel.Endpoint
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.lang.reflect.Array.newArray(Native Method)[:1.7.0_79]
 at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:70)[:1.7.0_79]

Comment: I am not sure if a camel Endpoint can be exported as a CXF service. It was never meant to be used over a remote connection. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I want to be able to  use a web service deployed on another remote machine. ( I'm using tomcat) This service service will be called in a camel route.

Comment: You could solve this by adding a zookeeper entry for your tomcat service. DOSGi can then offer you a client proxy for it. Unfortunately creating the entry would require custom code but it can be done